# WordPress Settings / General / Site Language Option Disappear - Mac OS

Tags: wordpress

While I try to change WordPress language on **localhost** **Mac OS** machine, I got this Warning message and I couldn't find **Site Language** option on **General Settings** page.

> **Warning**: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with
>   WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have
>   problems, please try the [support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/). (WordPress could not
>   establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your
>   server administrator.) in
>   **/opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/translation-install.php**
>   on line **65**

My WordPress is the latest version **4.9.1**

Some people in WordPress support suggest to check the installation of curl in XAMPP web server and I check it and it works well. [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/warning-an-unexpected-error-occurred-showing-when-creating-a-plugin/)

I also checked the privilege of **../wordpress/wp-content/languages/** directory and chmod to 777

Any help, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from XAMPP to MAMP and this problem is solved.